# Access gatling session state within karate feature

Tags: karate

I would like to access the gatling session from within a karate feature. Is this possible?

For example there is a `userId` field present in the gatling session which I want to use.

My use case: 
I have a feature in which I create a so called app, and each app needs a unique appId, therefore I want to use the append the `userId` variable to an app name, effectively giving each virtual user its own appId.

```
Feature: Run an app

  Background:
    # userId is taken from gatling session
    * def appId = 'run_perf' + userId
```

It would be cool if karate allows to use the gatling session variables like any other variables. 
So if I access the `foo` variable, karate would first check if this variable is defined as a "normal" karate variable and if it does not find it it could check if such a variable is defined in the gatling session.

edit:

```
val runApp = scenario("runApp").exec(karateFeature("classpath:performance/createAndRunApp.feature"))

  setUp(
    runApp.inject(atOnceUsers(50)).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

If `createAndRunApp.feature` uses a constant `appId` (eg: `myId`) and I run this feature with 50 virtual users, all of them would ofc try to create an app with the Id `myId` and 49 would fail because an app with this Id does already exist.
What I want is that user 1 uses appId `myId1`, user 2 uses `myId2`, and so forth. This could be achieved by appending the value of the `userId` field from the gatling `Session` to the constant appId, or it could also be achieved by appending some random id like `UUID` but than its more difficult to see in the reports which user made a request cos I cannot know from `appId{Some-UUID}` which user it was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding this example.

The way it is designed is it assumes all the logic is in Karate. So as long as you perhaps call some re-usable scripts, and return variables back to the "calling" script, you should have all the info you need.

What I would have expected is you have say a top-level `user-flow.feature` which calls a `create-app.feature` which returns the created app-id to the caller - and everything just works.

You can certainly submit a feature-request - but I'd really need a simple but self-contained example so that I can understand what you mean by a variable in a Gatling session.

EDIT - will be available in 1.0: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1382

Comment: In gatling each virtual user has a `Session`(https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/session/Session.scala) on which you can get and set variables. One of the fixed fields of a session is the `userId`, so each virtual user has a unique id.
When 10 users now run my `create-app.feature`, each of them need to choose a unique `appId` and a simple way of doing this would be to append the `userId` to the `appId`. Another way which would also work is append a UUID is something but than it is harder to track the relation between user and app.

Comment: @leozilla - that's interesting. I can certainly expose the gatling session to a karate test. but that breaks the concept of being able to use karate without gatling. suggestion: create a Java / Scala singleton that you instantiate at the beginning of a gatling test. access this from your karate features. if you need tweaks - I do insist on a working example so that I can debug / test. hope that is fair.

Comment: i have updated the original question. I will try with the singleton or something else. Will let you know how it worked out.